# Craft 2 to Craft update - timeout when updating database

Tags: craft3, updates, timeout

I am trying to update a site from Craft 2 to Craft 3. I first set up a new server, installed Craft 3, copied over config settings from the original site, and moved over a copy the original database. I have done this successfully on quite a few Craft 2 to 3 updates with no problem.

After pointing my browser to mysite/admin I got the prompt to finish up / update the database as expected, but the process timed out. The sql file I moved over is about 8mb, not especially large. In any case, is there any way I can run the database update process from the console in order to avoid the timeout issue?

Answer (score 2):

The [console command](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html) you are looking for is:

```
./craft migrate/all
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer, thanks to @Brandon Kelly: ./craft migrate/up --track=craft